# Error on "Ionic cordova build android"

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, gradle

I'm trying to build a APP on Android but always returns this error

> ANDROID_HOME=/usr/lib/android-sdk
>   JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_171-amd64
>   studio
>   Error occurred during initialization of VM
>   java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
>   (node:4451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: /usr/lib/gradle/4.8.1/bin/gradle: Command failed with exit code 1
>       at ChildProcess.whenDone (/home/daniel/Documentos/todo/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:169:23)
>       at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
>       at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
>       at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
>       at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
>   (node:4451) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>   (node:4451) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My config is :

cli packages: (/usr/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0 
Gulp CLI              : CLI version 3.9.1 Local version 3.9.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android 7.0.0
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.4
```

System:

```
Node : v8.11.3
npm  : 5.6.0 
OS   : Linux 4.15
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : not set
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

Comment: pretending `ANDROID_HOME` would not be set is non-sense, while the log tells otherwise ...possibly it is being set to the wrong location; ever verified that?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, and solved running the command

```
ionic doctor check
```

That command scan your project and fix the outdated modules

Answer (score 0):

Could you please follow those steps ? If there is anything wrong after this I might help, and we have a common ground of the steps you took to setup the build. Without knowing what you did to set the system up or see spefcific errors it is really hard to help you

[How to setup ionic android build on linux](https://gist.github.com/lirantal/736e06a4ba562887a075dfa7698d844d)